# Redux form submitSucceeded property is set to true before the submission fails

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am dispatching an action which makes an api call in redux-form asyncValidate method. The api call fails. I am trying to show the messages about successful and unsuccessful submit in the form, but submitSucceeded is always getting set to true before the api call fails. Therefore, I always get the message about successful submit before seeing the error message.

Before using asyncValidate, I tried the same thing inside onSubmit method. I throw an error inside the action, but that doesn`t help.

Here is the code for component:

```
    const SubmissionForm = ({handleSubmit, submitFailed, submitSucceeded, asyncValidating}) => 
    <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    {submitFailed && <div>Failed</div>}
    {submitSucceeded && <div>Succeeded</div>}
    {asyncValidating && <div>Validating...</div>}
        <Field name={`name`} type="text" component={"input"} />
    </Form>

    const enhancer = {

    connect(null,{ editUser }),

    reduxForm({
    form: "editUser",
    asyncBlurFields: [],
    onSubmit: () => {},
    asyncValidate: async (data, _, {editUser}) => {
      return await editUser(data)
        }
     })
   }
```

And the code for action:

```
    const editUserStart = (user) => ({ type: EDIT_USER_START, user })
    const editUserSuccess = (user) => ({ type: EDIT_USER_SUCCESS, user })
    const editUserError = (error) => ({ type: EDIT_USER_ERROR, error })

    const editUser = (data) => async dispatch => {
    dispatch(editUserStart(data))
    try {
    const response = await api.postUserInfo(data)
    if (response.error) {
      throw new Error(response.error)
    }else{
    return dispatch(editUserSuccess(data))
    }
    } catch (e) {
    dispatch(setSubmitFailed("editUser", e))
    dispatch(editUserError(e))
    }
    }
```

How can I prevent the form from setting submitSucceeded before failing?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem is with editUser function. Can you please console.log this `const response = await api.postUserInfo(data)` and make sure that response.error exists?

Comment: Yes, I receive such json
`{timestamp: "2019-01-29T13:07:06.555+0000", status: 404, error: "Not Found", message: "No message available", path: "/user"}
error: "Not Found"
message: "No message available"
path: "/user"
status: 404
timestamp: "2019-01-29T13:07:06.555+0000"}
`

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue